# Synchronizing looping threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

I am making some multi-threaded video game code. Before I began coding I looked at an article describing vaguely Valve's solution to multi-threaded game design. A key concept I gleaned from the article is thread synchronization. I don't know if this is how Valve does it but I imagined multiple threads each executing a game loop. At the end of each iteration, the threads pause and wait for other threads to finish their current iteration, then synchronize shared data. I figure that besides the overhead is this management scheme, there would be no different to just let the threads operate completely asynchronously. The article mentioned a thread used exclusively for syncing but I am trying to get a different solution to work correctly. This is how I (try) to do it:

```
        // at end of loop on each thread...
        sig_thread_done();

        while (!is_sync_done())
        {
            PauseExecution(1);
        }
```

sig_thread_done and is_sync_done are function objects from another class that controls a list of all "threads". These functions look like this:

```
bool Core::IsFrameDone()
{
    MutexLock lock(manager_mutex);

    if (waiting_components == -1)
    {
        waiting_components = 0;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Core::SignalFrameDone()
{
    MutexLock lock(manager_mutex);

    if (++waiting_components == (int)components.size()) // components == threads
    {
        //sync shared data...
        waiting_components = -1; // -1 signifies that all threads have completed their iteration
    }
}
```

The problem is that a fast thread can exit its waiting loop and come back around to it again before other threads have a chance to exit there's. So the other threads miss the exit through is_sync_done returning false before another thread begins waiting and the whole system gets stuck waiting forever.

I can't find an easy way to resolve this issue. I really like this approach because synchronization doesn't get stalled while some independent thread performs the sync.

I appreciate any insight or suggestions anyone has to offer.

[Link to article.](http://techreport.com/articles.x/11237)

Comment: suggest you link to the article you are referencing.

Comment: Conceptually, you try to implement a barrier - so why not use a tested implementation instead, e.g. `pthread_barrier`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to re-invent a [Thread barrier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/barrier.html).

Comment: That seems to be what everyone else is saying. I've never heard of a thread barrier before, I suppose I should have done more reading before doing I started this project. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Much thanks, dude, never knew about that synchronization primitive!

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you want to sync on a barrier, with something like a Win32 Event (or an array thereof), this makes sure you cannot get the situation you described (the barrier ensures that everything syncs up to the same *frame*) while at the same time freeing CPU time, as waiting on events is done as a kernel signal, and sleeps the thread till that signal is received. You'd also what to use wait-free algorithms in there, these work particularly well if you have a job/task based threading model, where certain things can be decoupled from the system.

Also, [here](http://valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/GDC2007_SourceMulticore.pdf) is a better publication on multi-threading the source engine, its far more in depth and technical (they also specifically state that they avoid mutexes for this sort of thing).

Comment: Thanks. Before I tried this I had all threads run asynchronously and used mutexes where necessary. This will eliminate the overhead of all that sporadic syncing.