# How to avoid deadlock when synching loops with barrier

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, synchronization

The program I am implementing involves iterating over a medium amount of independent data, performing some computation, collecting the result, and then looping back over again. This loop needs to execute very quickly. To solve this, I am trying to implement the following thread pattern.

[image: Thread Pattern]

Rather than spawn threads in setup and join them in collect, I would like to spawn all threads initially, and keep them synchronized throughout their loops. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959604/synchronizing-looping-threads) regarding [thread barriers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier) had initially seemed to point me in the right direction, but my implementation of them is not working. Below is my example

```
int main() {

    int counter = 0;
    int threadcount = 10;

    auto on_completion = [&]() noexcept {
        ++counter; // Incremenent counter
    };

    std::barrier sync_point(threadcount, on_completion);

    auto work = [&]() {
        while(true)
            sync_point.arrive_and_wait(); // Keep cycling the sync point
    };

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < threadcount; ++i) 
        threads.emplace_back(work); // Start every thread
    

    for (auto& thread : threads) 
        thread.join();
    
}
```

To keep things as simple as possible, there is no computation being done in the worker threads, and I have done away with the setup thread. I am simply cycling the threads, syncing them after each cycle, and keeping a count of how many times they have looped. However, this code is deadlocking very quickly. More threads = faster deadlock. Adding work/delay inside the compute threads slows down the deadlock, but does not stop it.

Am I abusing the thread barrier? Is this unexpected behavior? Is there a cleaner way to implement this pattern?

**Edit**

It looks like removing the `on_completion` gets rid of the deadlock. I tried a different approach to meet the synchronization requirements without using the function, but it still deadlocks fairly quickly.

```
int threadcount = 10;

std::barrier start_point(threadcount + 1);
std::barrier stop_point(threadcount + 1);

auto work = [&](int i) {
    while(true) {
        start_point.arrive_and_wait();
        stop_point.arrive_and_wait();
    }
};

std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for (int i = 0; i < threadcount; ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back(work, i);
}

while (true) {
    std::cout << "Setup" << std::endl;
    start_point.arrive_and_wait(); // Sync to start
    // Workers do work here
    stop_point.arrive_and_wait(); // Sync to end
    std::cout << "Collect" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove your `on_completion` function?

Comment: @NicolBolas Removing it and moving the counter to the worker thread with no setup or collection does get rid of the deadlock. I tried a different implementation to sync them with setup and all (see edit) however this still leads to deadlock

Comment: Your second version now has a data race, since every thread is doing a read/modify/write on the same object with no synchronization.

Comment: @NicolBolas Just corrected it by removing access to any data inside the worker threads, the behavior however remains the same.

Comment: Just a suggestion: have you tried to spezialize the barrier: `std::barrier<decltype(on_completion)>`? The difference is that _by using the default template argument the completion step is run as part of the call to arrive that caused the expected count to reach zero and for other specializations, the completion step is run on one of the threads that arrived at the barrier during the phase._ So in the first case, the thread that caused the counter to hit zero runs the completition function and otherwise some randomly chosen thread. If it's worth noting, i've run it now many times, no deadlock.

Comment: As a hint (similar task as yours but C related and `pthread_barrier_wait`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008816/how-to-properly-synchronize-threads-at-barriers/69062834#69062834

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Would you mind sharing the system specs that you ran on without deadlock? I tried running identical code on a different system and it is working there. I am starting to wonder if it is a bug.


System that worked:
Intel, macOS, clang

Did not work on:
AMD, Windows 11 MinGW, GCC

Comment: Linux 5.19.10-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC x86_64 Intel GNU/Linux; gcc (GCC) 12.2.0. I've realized that i've tested only in debug mode (-g), i'll test it with optimization on.

Comment: I should also remark, that i have a `std::printf` in the completition (after `++counter`) and the thread function (before `arrive_and_wait`). But even withou any output, i do not have a deadlock.